# Django test fails when creating test database

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-testing

It fails with a number of related_name-related issues. Of course when running the actual dev server (with `./manage.py runserver`) this doesn't happen, I'm guessing maybe the models are being generated twice? I'm running psycopg2 2.4.1, and here's my test output:

```
(venv)lacrymology@Roller:boilerplate$ ./manage.py test
Creating test database for alias 'default'...
Error: One or more models did not validate:
l10n.address: Accessor for field 'user_shipping' clashes with related field 'User.shipping_address'. Add a related_name argument to the definition for 'user_shipping'.
l10n.address: Reverse query name for field 'user_shipping' clashes with related field 'User.shipping_address'. Add a related_name argument to the definition for 'user_shipping'.
l10n.address: Accessor for field 'user_billing' clashes with related field 'User.billing_address'. Add a related_name argument to the definition for 'user_billing'.
l10n.address: Reverse query name for field 'user_billing' clashes with related field 'User.billing_address'. Add a related_name argument to the definition for 'user_billing'.
custom_registration.profile: Accessor for field 'user' clashes with related field 'User.profile'. Add a related_name argument to the definition for 'user'.
custom_registration.profile: Reverse query name for field 'user' clashes with related field 'User.profile'. Add a related_name argument to the definition for 'user'.
addressmodel.address: Accessor for field 'user_shipping' clashes with related field 'User.shipping_address'. Add a related_name argument to the definition for 'user_shipping'.
addressmodel.address: Reverse query name for field 'user_shipping' clashes with related field 'User.shipping_address'. Add a related_name argument to the definition for 'user_shipping'.
addressmodel.address: Accessor for field 'user_billing' clashes with related field 'User.billing_address'. Add a related_name argument to the definition for 'user_billing'.
addressmodel.address: Reverse query name for field 'user_billing' clashes with related field 'User.billing_address'. Add a related_name argument to the definition for 'user_billing'.
profiles.profile: Accessor for field 'user' clashes with related field 'User.profile'. Add a related_name argument to the definition for 'user'.
profiles.profile: Reverse query name for field 'user' clashes with related field 'User.profile'. Add a related_name argument to the definition for 'user'.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was an issue with django-shop tests, as described in this comment: [Django test fails when creating test database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10058277/django-test-fails-when-creating-test-database#comment12902711_10062087)

I could find no way around it without changing the app's code, so I ended up just testing my own apps (running `./manage.py test myapp` instead of `./manage.py test`

Answer (score 1):

It is highly possible that your test.py imports an app which is not inside INSTALLED_APP but has some model fields pointing to the collided model. Try to grep **user_shipping** inside apps which are imported in test.py but not inside INSTALLED_APPS, and replace it.

`./manage.py validate`, which will be called internally by `./manage.py runserver`, only checks models loaded from apps inside INSTALLED_APP and thus there was no error when you ran devserver. However, imports inside test.py will cause extra models of non-installed apps, if there is any, to be loaded and then collision will happen.

Comment: I have no tests of my own so far, so I should figure out which app tests are being ran when it fails?

Comment: @Lacrymology sure, you could: 1. find if there is any user_shipping related_name in you model and rename it; 2. use pdb or signal to check the collided model, here the `User`, in the early stage of test just before validate happens, to check which model defines related_name `user_shipping` on the `User`

Comment: hm.. this seems to be an issue with django-shop. It defines a default Address model, but it recommends you write your own. Then it does some magic in it's models file so either your defined model or it's own can be accessed from the same name. If I remove "shop" from INSTALLED_APPS then a lot of the errors disappear

Comment: @Lacrymology yes, it highly possible. I just downloaded django-shop and found `user_billing` and `user_shipping` inside it, seems related_name `shipping_address` and `billing_address` have not been used in the other code of django-shop. You could change them then.

Comment: I'll go talk to the django-shop people